# Stream multiple docker container audio

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I want to run multiple docker containers on a machine and stream the audio via RTP. I can run apps with sound with this command:

```
sudo docker run -it \
    --device /dev/snd \
    -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native \
    -v ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native:${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native \
    -v ~/.config/pulse/cookie:/root/.config/pulse/cookie \
    --group-add $(getent group audio | cut -d: -f3) \
    
    ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

It works fine and when i play any sound in the container it plays and i can hear it and i can stream it with FFmpeg. The problem is when i run multiple containers and play any sound from any container, it seems they are using the same sink in pulseaudio server so i can't separate them and each stream client hear all the sounds from all the running containers. How can i achieve my goal?
My FFmpeg Stream code:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -c:a libopus -f rtp rtp://$IP:4001
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but it looks as if you are using `alsa` instead of `pulse`, and also using two codecs (`-acodec` and `-a:c` are the same)

Can you try:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -ab 128k -ac 2 -c:a libopus -f rtp rtp://$IP:400
```

Also, if you're trying to run pulse audio inside a docker container, you might need to start the `pulseaudio` daemon:

```
# your docker apt-get:
apt-get install -y pulseaudio

# your entrypoint/command script:
pulseaudio &

# or, if using root (dont)
pulseaudio --system &
```